# How to display a field automatically after selecting an option in a multiple insert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I choose an option in 'Nama Bahan', it would automatically fill the `stok` field by the `total_bahan` (based on the data which is stored in a database).

The problem is the script doesn't run correctly when I add multiple inserts, as in the picture, it just runs in the first row, but when I choose an option in the second or third row, the `stok` column is still blank. How should it be?

[image: CLICK TO SEE THE PICTURE]

Here is the script:

```
<script src="<?= base_url('assets/'); ?>vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      var i =1;
      $('#add').click(function(){
        i++;

        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"> <td><select name="bhn_id[]" id="bhn_id" class="form-control form-control-sm bhn_id"><option value="">-- Pilih Bahan --</option><?php foreach ($data_bahan->result_array() as $key => $tb_bahan) : ?>
                            <option data-id="<?=$tb_bahan['stok'] ?>" value="<?=$tb_bahan['id_bhn'] ?>"><?= $tb_bahan['nm_bhn']. "  ". "(". $tb_bahan['nm_satuan'] . ")" . "(". $tb_bahan['stok'] . ")" ?></option><?php endforeach; ?>
                              <?= form_error('bhn_id', '<small class="text-danger">', '</small>'); ?>
                          </select><?= form_error('bhn_id', '<small class="text-danger">', '</small>'); ?></td><td width="100"><input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm jlh_keluar"  name="jlh_keluar[]" id="jlh_keluar" value="<?= set_value('jlh_keluar'); ?>"></td><td width="100"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm stok"  name="stok[]" id="stok" readonly value="<?= set_value('stok'); ?>"></td><td align="center" width="100"><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm btn_remove">x</button></td></tr>');

        });
    
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
      var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
      $("#row"+button_id+"").remove();
      });
    $(document).on('submit', '#add_jenis', function(){
      $.ajax({
        url:"<?= base_url('m_form_bahan_keluar/tambah');?>",
        method:"POST",
        data:$('#add_jenis').serialize(),
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#add_jenis')[0].reset("");
        }
      });
    });

   });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bhn_id').change(function(){
    var part = $(this).children("option:selected").data('id');
    $('#stok').val(part);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `select` should get a unique id. Right now you are assigning each as "bhn_id". The code starting `$('#bhn_id').change(` should really use a class selector and should delegate the change event i.e. `$(document).on('change','select.bhn_id'`. Alternatively add the change event to the add click function and use the new unique id assigned to the `select`.